# Error while get JobOperatorImpl with Thorntail (Wildfly Swarm) and JBeret

Tags: wildfly-swarm, jberet, thorntail

I need to get JobOperatorImpl for dealing with programmatically defined jobs in JBeret. I use Thorntail as a container with io.thorntail:batch-jberet dependency.

```
JobOperatorImpl jobOperator = (JobOperatorImpl) JobOperatorContext.getJobOperatorContext().getJobOperator();
```

But I get an exception:`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet.deployment.JobOperatorService cannot be cast to org.jberet.operations.JobOperatorImpl`

It works normally when I use JBeret dependency without Thorntail fraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast it to `org.jberet.operations.AbstractJobOperator`.

It should provide all methods you need for managing jobs.

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks! Now I have another problem WFLYBATCH000005: The job name 'test01_1' was not found for the deployment. But it is the next challenge.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet.deployment.JobOperatorService` can only be cast to `javax.batch.operations.JobOperator` and not the JBeret implementation class

Comment: Yes, Ken, you are right, but how can I run job defined in java not in xml? I know only one way, by JobOperatorImpl.